# Pass fetch api results to function and use the processed data from the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fetch, fetch-api

I am fetching numbers from this api

```
let fetchRes = fetch("https://api.lunarcrush.com/v2?data=assets&key=n8dyddsipg5611qg6bst9&symbol=AVAX")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.data[0].market_cap;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

I want the numbers fetched (example- 7692083188) to be displayed in like 7.69B.
I know this code for converting but how do I connect both codes to acheive my data displayed as 7.69B?

```
function convertToInternationalCurrencySystem (labelValue) {

    // Nine Zeroes for Billions
    return Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+9

    ? (Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+9).toFixed(2) + "B"
    // Six Zeroes for Millions 
    : Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+6

    ? (Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+6).toFixed(2) + "M"
    // Three Zeroes for Thousands
    : Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+3

    ? (Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+3).toFixed(2) + "K"

    : Math.abs(Number(labelValue));

}

( convertToInternationalCurrencySystem (7692083188) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set your `#result` innerHTML to `convertToInternationalCurrencySystem(result.data[0].market_cap)` by changing this line:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.data[0].market_cap;
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = convertToInternationalCurrencySystem(result.data[0].market_cap);
```

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above:

```js
function convertToInternationalCurrencySystem(labelValue) {

    // Nine Zeroes for Billions
    return Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+9

    ? (Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+9).toFixed(2) + "B"
    // Six Zeroes for Millions 
    : Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+6

    ? (Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+6).toFixed(2) + "M"
    // Three Zeroes for Thousands
    : Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+3

    ? (Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+3).toFixed(2) + "K"

    : Math.abs(Number(labelValue));

}

let fetchRes = fetch("https://api.lunarcrush.com/v2?data=assets&key=n8dyddsipg5611qg6bst9&symbol=AVAX")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((result) => {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = convertToInternationalCurrencySystem(result.data[0].market_cap);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

```html
<h1 id="result"></h1>
```